# SFINAE for constructor parameters

Tags: c++, class, constructor, sfinae

I'm trying to create a sample class which has different specializations according to whether its template parameter can be constructed with certain parameters. In my sample, with a simple `int`. I've tried with:

```
template<class A_t>
struct creator
{
    A_t* ptr = nullptr;
};

template<class A_t>
struct creator<decltype(A_t(int()))>
{
    A_t* ptr = new A_t(5);
};

struct A
{
    int i;

    A(int i) : i(i) {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << creator<A>().ptr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My intention is that it prints a memory address of a automatically constructed object. However, it is printing a 0. So, it's taking the non-specialized template.

`A_t` is deducible with that syntax, among other things because `A_t` is given explicitly. Besides, `decltype(A_t(int())` has type `A_t` (and not `A_t&&` for example), a simple test:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(A(int()), A>::value << std::endl;
```

prints 1.

However, that implementation works:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A_t, class = A_t>
struct creator
{
    A_t* ptr = nullptr;
};

template<class A_t>
struct creator<A_t, decltype(A_t(int()))>
{
    A_t* ptr = new A_t(5);
};

struct A
{
    int i;

    A(int i) : i(i) {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << creator<A>().ptr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3bfa27026028b2e) test with two classes, one accepting an `int` as parameter, and other which doesn't.

Why is the first approach not working?

Comment: "`A_t` is deducible with that syntax" - [apparently clang disagrees with you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef8e660b39987927). I'd have to think about why (in a meeting and supposed to be paying attention =P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best gloss of the thinking behind your question is:

For a given instantiating type `U` => `A_t`, if the conversion
`U(int)` is undefined then the substitution `U(int)` => `A_t(int)`
will fail in the context `decltype(A_t(int()))` and the specialization:

```
template<class A_t>
struct creator<decltype(A_t(int()))>
{
    A_t* ptr = new A_t(5);
};
```

will be eliminated, leaving only the base template instantiation. But if the
conversion `U(int)` is defined that substitution will succeed.

Then, because:

```
std::is_same<U,decltype(U(int()))>::value == true
```

both candidates:

```
// Tweedledum, with of U => A_t
struct creator<U>
{
    U* ptr = nullptr;
};
```

and:

```
// Tweedledee, with U => decltype(A_t(int()))
struct creator<U>
{
    U* ptr = new U(5);
};
```

are in the running.

Then, the *most specialized* candidate will be chosen, which will be `Tweedledee`,
because satisfying `U` => `decltype(A_t(int()))` constrains `U` more precisely than
the bare `U => A_t`.

This reasoning relies implicitly on it being *deducible* for `Teedledee` that `U` = `decltype(A_t(int()))` when `U` => `A_t`;
which boils down to it being deducible that `U(int)` = `A_t(int)` in the sole template argument `decltype(A_t(int()))`.

You believe that is so and then wonder how gcc can pick `Tweedledum`.

As @WhozCraig pointed out, clang++ expressly rejects your deducibility premiss:-

```
$ clang++-3.8 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 main.cpp
main.cpp:10:8: warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
struct creator<decltype(A_t(int()))>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'A_t'
template<class A_t>
               ^
```

[So does MSVC++](http://rextester.com/EFIRA27724).

And it turns out that gcc has been induced into a diagnostic lapse here by
the unlucky phrasing of your SFINAE locution, `decltype(A_t(int()))`

If you replace that with `decltype(A_t{int()})`, then gcc also [gets with the program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9200ca3c4784551):

```
$ g++-6 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14 main.cpp
main.cpp:10:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
 struct creator<decltype(A_t{int()})>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:8: note:         ‘A_t’
```

After that, clang++ is the only compiler of the three that will
compile the program at all - and instantiates `creator<A>` from the base template.

This eventual consensus that `A_t` is *not* deducible in `decltype(A_t{int()})`
is endorsed by the C++14 Standard:

> Deducing template arguments from a type        [temp.deduct.type]
>
> 1 Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but in each case
> a type that is specified in terms of template parameters (call it P) is compared
> with an actual type (call it A), and an attempt is made to find template argument
> values (a type for a type parameter, a value for a non-type parameter, or a
> template for a template parameter) that will make P, after substitution of the
> deduced values (call it the deduced A), compatible with A.
>
> ...
>
> 4 In most cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose
> P participate in template argument deduction... In certain contexts, however,
> the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values
> of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified.
> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly
> specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 5 The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> ...
>
> (5.2) - The expression of a decltype-specifier.
>
> ...

Para 4 also explains why your second approach succeeds.